# How to show 2 button same row under image?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to show button in same row under image. This is my code it can show button but not same row.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image(
              image: AssetImage('images/111.jpg'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('aaa'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('bbb'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I change code to child: Row like this.

```
 body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Image(
          image: AssetImage('images/111.jpg'),
        ),
        

      ],
    ),

    child: Row(
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('aaa'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('bbb'),
        ),

    ),
  ),
```

It's show error child was already specified. How to show 2 button same row under image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot have two childs under Center
2. you need children for widgets under Row.

Try

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Image(
          image: AssetImage('images/111.jpg'),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children : [
        
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('aaa'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('bbb'),
        ),
        ]
          

    )
        

      ],
    

    
  )
  );}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the `column` for?
I believe that if you want to show the buttons right below your image, your `row` should be inside the `column`, below your `image`. Something like this:

```
body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Image(
          image: AssetImage('images/111.jpg'),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children:<Widget> [
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('aaa'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('bbb'),
            ),
          ]
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```